# Add item to empty array in C and getting array length

Tags: c, arrays

I've taking many attempts at solving this problem but failed every time.

I have an array

```
char *array[1024] = {};
```

Now I would like to add an item to the array and would also access the items by numbers

For example:
`array[0]` would be the first item
`array[1]` would be the second
`array[2]` would be the third item

But also I would like to know how many items are in the array so I could use something like

```
for(int i = 0; i <= totalitemsinarray; i++) {
    print(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: "I have an empty array " That array isn't empty. The number of items in the array is `1024`.

Comment: In C, the size of an array does not change after it's created. That array holds 1024 elements (either uninitialized or NULL, I forget which).

Comment: And since your edit, that array now holds 0 elements.

Comment: I may just have to reinitialize the size of the array every item I add but how can I do that?

Comment: @AdrianWebster That's what I just said... In C, the size of an array does not change after it's created. Ever. Your only option is to create a new array that's bigger, and to do that you'll probably need `malloc` (because local variables aren't flexible enough)

Comment: C doesn't support empty arrays. (Some compilers might permit them as an extension.)

Comment: @AdrianWebster In C you can't change an array's size after declaring it. What you can do is to allocate dynamic memory to make a new buffer, assign that to a pointer and use it like an array (even though it is not technically an array).

Comment: @KeithThompson C does in structure declarations as the last element. That's a new rule in C99.

Comment: @FUZxxl: That's not an empty array.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, okay, we are fighting with words here, but please read ISO 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 ¶3.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Words are the only weapon we've got. 8-)} But see the end of paragraph 18 in the same section: "If this array would have no elements, it behaves as if it had one element but the behavior is undefined if any attempt is made to access that element or to generate a pointer one past it." The standard tries very hard to avoid empty arrays. Note also that a VLA with a length of 0 has undefined behavior (if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the size of an array in C. You can however allocate a sufficiently large array and then fill it up with entries. First, declare an array with a sufficient size, say, 1024.

```
char *array[1024];
```

Then declare a variable `fill` that counts the number of used slots in `array`. Initialize it to `0` as 0 slots are used in the beginning. Then, each time you insert an item, increment `fill`:

```
array[fill++] = ...;
...
array[fill++] = ...;
```

Make sure that you never attempt to insert more than 1024 items into the array, C doesn't check that for you.

For a more flexible approach, use `malloc()` to allocate memory for the array and then periodically enlarge it with `realloc()` when it's full. If you increase the array size in exponential steps (say, multiply with Φ = 0.5 + 0.5 √2 ≈ 1.61), this runs in O(1) amortised time per entry inserted.

Comment: Edit: Ahh I see now. Thanks!

Comment: @cmaster I gave this answer before OP removed the 1024 from the array declaration.

Comment: array[i] represent the i-item (+1 if you count from zero)

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli Where do I say that?

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. I've figured it out. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: @FUZxxl Was for Adrian who edited hos reply to your post

Comment: @FUZxxl Ah, I didn't see the question before the change. Removed my comment and my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do what you're asking directly with C. One option could be if you knew that only certain values were valid. For example, you have an array of `char *`s so often people use `NULL` as a flag/invalid value. In that case you could initialize your array to have all `NULL`s and use that to know the size of the array:

```
char *array[1024];

memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

/* .... */

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(char*); i++) {
    if (array[i]) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array[1024] = {};
```

First, that is an array with 1024 char pointers/strings. Those elements can be 0s or plain garbage. If you don't plan to set them all you may want to nullify the array.

For the matter of storing the values and the count you might want to have a look at structs. For example:

```
typedef struct elem {
    int count;
    char *value;
} elem;
```

Then `elem.count` would be the number and `elem.value` would be the value accordingly.

And then initialize them in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The only really valid way to approach this, is to dynamically grow the array. Allocate the array on the heap, and manage two counts: 1. the count of currently used elements, and 2. the count of elements for which you currently have memory allocated. Something like this:

```
//the setup
size_t arrayLength = 0, allocatedSize = 8;
int* array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * allocatedSize);

//grow the array -> first check that we have space to add an element
if(arrayLength == allocatedSize) {
    array = realloc(array, allocatedSize *= 2);
    assert(array);
}
assert(arrayLength < allocatedSize);

//grow the array -> add an element
array[arrayLength++] = ...;
```

You see, the `realloc()` call is not too much hassle, but it will protect you from bugs when the requirements change. My experience is that any fixed limit in the code, as insanely large as it may seem to be, will eventually be exceeded, and miserable failure will result. The only safeguard is to use as much memory as needed everywhere.